# How to use a vibration sensor

Tags: sensor

I've recently begun doing a school project. For one of the subsystems , I intend to mount a buzzer and vibration sensor on a walking stick and configure it such that the buzzer sounds when the walking stick falls and hits the ground.

I'm assuming the the impact of the walking stick hitting the ground will cause some deflection on the tip of the vibration sensor which will generate a voltage signal.

The problem is that I cannot seem to get the vibration sensor to work. What I have done was just to connect it to a 5V DC source and a 1K Ohm resistor and measure the voltage drop across it when I push the tip with my finger. However , the voltage drop across this vibration sensor does not change no matter how much I deflect the tip.

I'm using a MEAS MSP-1006 ND vibration sensor.

Thank you.

Comment: I link to the spec sheet would help. http://www.meas-spec.com/downloads/LDT_Series.pdf This I assume.  It will output an AC voltage.. (not DC.)

Comment: I use this exact sensor in a product where I work. George is right in that it has an AC output (both pos and neg). For my purpose I rectified and boosted the output (it has a pretty small voltage response). If you are measuring with a multimeter you probably won't be able to see the voltage change. You'd need to use an oscilloscope.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold Oh sorry, yes that is the spec sheet of the component. Uh , where does it say on the spec sheet that it would ouput an AC voltage?

Comment: @I.Wolfe Oh I see. So if I connect the sensor to a resistance and a 5V dc source it should work right? Just that there will be an AC output at the 2 legs of the sensor.

Comment: @John, I don't think you need (or want) a 5V source.  I like to model (think of) a piezo as a voltage source with a capacitor in series,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piezoelectric_sensor.  You need to think about the impedance of the capacitance(at the frequency of interest) and the resistor you use to monitor it.

Comment: That datasheet assumes a lot of pre-knowledge. The only place that AC is mentioned directly is in the upper-left corner of the first page of the datasheet. "AC Coupled".  Please see their [selection guide](http://www.meas-spec.com/downloads/Choosing_the_Right_Type_of_Accelerometers.pdf) for an overview.  One thing to note is they say that the AC-coupled sensors can't measure static acceleration (such as gravity, or a steady push with your finger).

Comment: If you need more sensitivity, try googling "[piezo sensor amplifier](https://www.google.com/search?q=piezo+sensor+amplifier)" or similar. This will show a fairly simple way to boost it's sensitivity.

Comment: For this project I don't really have a choice except to use a DC source. I tried amplifying the vibration sensor output but was not able to get any readings on the oscilloscope.